# React Native Button Icon not showing

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I am using expo's snack, no icon ever showing correctly, what am I doing wrong?
I test this snack [https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html](https://snack.expo.io/?name=Button&description=https%3A%2F%2Fcallstack.github.io%2Freact-native-paper%2Fbutton.html&code=import%20*%20as%20React%20from%20%27react%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20Button%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native-paper%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20MyComponent%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%0A%20%20%3CButton%20icon%3D%22camera%22%20mode%3D%22contained%22%20onPress%3D%7B()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(%27Pressed%27)%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Press%20me%0A%20%20%3C%2FButton%3E%0A)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20MyComponent%3B&dependencies=react-native-paper), and many other snack, but it always show rectangle icon.

[image: Buttons always show rectangle icon]
I am using expo 36.0.0

Comment: For further users:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62025310/6321717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is visible in expo log as

> Tried to use the icon 'stepforward' in a component from 'react-native-paper', but 'react-native-vector-icons' could not be loaded.
>   To remove this warning, try installing 'react-native-vector-icons' or use another method to specify icon: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/icons.html. 
>   Even if you try to add package it's still not resolved by this, some issue in expo as reported here [Expo forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/icons-from-react-native-paper-not-appearing-on-web/31178/15)

Following is the workaround as [Snack link](http://%3Cdiv%20data-snack-id=%22@abdulwarris/button%22%20data-snack-platform=%22web%22%20data-snack-preview=%22true%22%20data-snack-theme=%22dark%22%20style=%22overflow:hidden;background:#212733;border:1px%20solid%20rgba(0,0,0,.08);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%25%22%3E%3C/div%3E%20%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22https://snack.expo.io/embed.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

1. Using Expo vector Icon

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

2.Get type

```
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
```

then pass as child