# Icons not showing in React Native + React Native Paper app

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

This is a fresh `React Native` app using `React Native Paper`. I followed the instructions at https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/getting-started.html and installed `react-native-paper` and `react-native-vector-icons`.

For some reason, none of the icons are showing in the app -- see below:
[image]

For example, I have a `Searchbar` at the top of this screen with the following code. As far as I can see, I don't even have to specify an icon there. It should automatically display a magnifying glass but no icon is showing.

```
<Searchbar placeholder="New to do item..." />
```

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you follow https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android?

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue. Thank you! Could you please copy and paste your response as an answer so that you get credit for your help? I'll accept yours as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 31):

Stop your application. Then go to project directory > open cmd > run `npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

cmd will show you linking is successful

Now run your app again

Comment: Someone give this answer a brownie... or maybe an accept...

Comment: `npx react-native link` doesn't work in version 0.69+ of react-native.  use `npx react-native-asset` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the installation steps as described here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android

React-native-paper uses MaterialCommunityIcons so remember to add it in the iconFontNames list in the steps above.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { Icon } from 'react-native-paper';

return(
<>
 <Icon source="car" size={30} />
 </>
)
```

Here this is the sample code and for this install the

```bash
npm i react-native-paper
```

and also in `android/app/build.gradle`
add

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

After referring the answer from Daviskitavi, what I just needed to do was to add this line as last line in android/app/build.gradle and rebuild the project. That's it.

apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")